# Open edit view controller from table view using core data

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, uiviewcontroller

In my iOS app I am using Core Data to show data on a table view. On the same view I have included an add button, which opens a new view controller where I can add a new record.

From this view I return to the table view and the new added record is shown correctly. Now, what I want to do is to select a row on the table view and open a new view controller to edit the fields of the record. The edit view controller name is `EditViewController`. Here is my table view controller source, so yo can please explain me the method to implement to pass the selected row record to the edit view controller, so I can later edit and save the information.
I have seen some examples for that question regarding the `didSelectedRowAtIndexPath` method, but all based on a storyboard, which I am not using in my project.

```
#import "RootViewController.h"
#import "AddToDoViewController.h"


@interface RootViewController ()
- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
@end


@implementation RootViewController

@synthesize fetchedResultsController, managedObjectContext,AddToDoButton;


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  [self setTitle:@"Today"];
  [[self navigationItem] setRightBarButtonItem:[self editButtonItem]];





  NSError *error = nil;
  if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error])
  {
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
  }
}
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  NSManagedObject *managedObject = [fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
  [[cell textLabel] setText:[[managedObject valueForKey:@"thingName"] description]];
  [[cell detailTextLabel] setText:[[managedObject valueForKey:@"thingDescription"] description]];
  [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Noteworthy" size:16.0f];
    cell.detailTextLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Noteworthy" size:14.0f];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table view data source
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
  return [[fetchedResultsController sections] count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
  return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
  if (cell == nil)
  {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle 
                                   reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"] autorelease];
  }

  [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];

  return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
  {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
    [context deleteObject:[fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![context save:&error])
    {
      NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
      abort();
    }
  }   
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath 
      toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath;
{  
  NSMutableArray *things = [[fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] mutableCopy];

  // Grab the item we're moving.
  NSManagedObject *thing = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:sourceIndexPath];

  // Remove the object we're moving from the array.
  [things removeObject:thing];
  // Now re-insert it at the destination.
  [things insertObject:thing atIndex:[destinationIndexPath row]];

  // All of the objects are now in their correct order. Update each
  // object's displayOrder field by iterating through the array.
  int i = 0;
  for (NSManagedObject *mo in things)
  {
    [mo setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i++] forKey:@"displayOrder"];
  }

  [things release], things = nil;

  [managedObjectContext save:nil];
}






#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Fetched results controller
- (IBAction)AddToDoAction:(id)sender {

    AddToDoViewController *viewController = [[AddToDoViewController alloc] init];
    [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];

}

- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
  if (fetchedResultsController) return fetchedResultsController;

  NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
  NSEntityDescription *entity = 
               [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"FavoriteThing" 
                           inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

  [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

  NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = 
              [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"displayOrder" 
                                          ascending:YES];

  NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] 
                              initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];  
  [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

  NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = 
              [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest 
                                                  managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext
                                                    sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"ThingsCache"];
  aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
  [self setFetchedResultsController:aFetchedResultsController];

  [aFetchedResultsController release];
  [fetchRequest release];
  [sortDescriptor release];
  [sortDescriptors release];

  return fetchedResultsController;
}    

- (void)dealloc {
  [fetchedResultsController release];
  [managedObjectContext release];


  [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Hi again. I have done following after the answer from @flexaddicted:
I have add following code to my EditToDoViewController.h file at the interface block:

```
NSManagedObject *selectedObject;
```

And also following declaration:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSManagedObject *selectedObject;
```

And in my EditToDoViewController.m file i have added following code:

```
@synthesize selectedObject;
```

The didSelectRowAtIndexPath method changed to:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    EditToDoViewController *detailViewController = [[EditToDoViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"EditToDoViewController" bundle:nil];
    NSManagedObject *selectedObject = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    EditToDoViewController.selectedObject = selectedObject;

}
```

But at this point I am receiving this error message:
 Property 'selectedObject' not found on object of type 'EditToDoViewController'

I think I have well declared the property 'selectedObject', I don't understand the error....
Thank you

Comment: Third line of last snippet is not correct. Should be `detailViewController.selectedObject`.

Comment: you are right... thanko you again, I hope this solve my question for today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1

Implement the correct delegate method for `UITableView`, that is `UITableViewDelegate`.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // do something here (see Step 2 and 3)
}
```

Step 2

Retrieve the correct item.

```
NSManagedObject *mo = [yourResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Step 3

Present a modal controller passing it data. An alternative is to wrap the controller you are using in a `UINavigationController` and do a push of a new controller. Example.

```
 YourAdditionalViewController *ac = [[YourAdditionalViewController alloc] init];
 ac.setMo = mo; // as a property or passed to a custom init method of YourAdditionalController
 [self presentViewController:ac animated:YES completion: nil];
```

So to recap.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSManagedObject *mo = [yourResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    YourAdditionalViewController *ac = [[YourAdditionalViewController alloc] init];
    ac.setMo = mo; // as a property or passed to a custom init method of YourAdditionalController
    [self presentViewController:ac animated:YES completion: nil];
}
```

Let me know if I need to improve my answer.

P.S. Check the code since I've written without Xcode support.

Comment: Thank you @flexaddicted, let me please take a look at your proposal, I will tell you if I need further explanations.

Comment: Thank you @flexaddicted, I have implemented your code, updated with real identities: - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSManagedObject *mo = [fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    
    EditToDoViewController *ac = [[EditToDoViewController alloc] init];
    ac.setMo = mo; // as a property or passed to a custom init method of YourAdditionalController
    [self presentViewController:ac animated:YES completion: nil];
}...but now I would need how to receive the data sent by the line ac.setMo = mo in my EditVC file

Comment: Could you please edit your question and add details there? Thanks

Comment: Thank you @flexaddicted, I have update my question following your instructions...